# Django - Change Form not working

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I'm having some problems with my Django site. I'm trying to build an ecommerce. I have a custom user model, with some fields that i needed (like address, email, etc). Here's the code for it:

```
class UsuarioFunnaticos(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    nome_completo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cep_entrega_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=9)
    rua_entrega_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    bairro_entrega_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    numero_entrega_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    complemento_entrega_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

    ACRE = 'AC'
    ALAGOAS = 'AL'

    # Some other choices

    SERGIPE = 'SE'
    TOCANTINS = 'TO' 

    ESTADOS = (
    (ACRE, 'Acre'),
    (ALAGOAS, 'Alagoas'),
    (AMAPA, 'Amapa'),
    (AMAZONAS, 'Amazonas'),
    (BAHIA,'Bahia'),
    (CEARA,'Ceara'),
    (DISTRITO_FEDERAL,'Distrito Federal'),
    (ESPIRITO_SANTO,'Espirito Santo'),
    (GOIAS,'Goias'),
    (MARANHAO,'Maranhao'),
    (MATO_GROSSO,'Mato Grosso'),
    (MATO_GROSSO_DO_SUL,'Mato Grosso do Sul'),
    (MINAS_GERAIS,'Minas Gerais'),
    (PARA,'Para'),
    (PARAIBA,'Paraiba'),
    (PARANA,'Parana'),
    (PERNAMBUCO,'Pernambuco'),
    (PIAUI,'Piaui'),
    (RIO_DE_JANEIRO,'Rio de Janeiro'),
    (RIO_GRANDE_DO_NORTE,'Rio Grande Do Norte'),
    (RIO_GRANDE_DO_SUL,'Rio Grande Do Sul'),
    (RONDONIA,'Rondonia'),
    (RORAIMA,'Roraima'),
    (SANTA_CATARINA,'Santa Catarina'),
    (SAO_PAULO,'Sao Paulo'),
    (SERGIPE,'Sergipe'),
    (TOCANTINS,'Tocantins'),        
    )

    estado_entrega_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ESTADOS)
    cidade_entrega_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=90)
    telefone = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    objects = UsuarioFunnaticosManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.nome_completo

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.nome_completo

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

On the admin, i have an UsuarioFunnaticosChangeForm, and it works perfectly on the Django admin. The code for it is:

```
class UsuarioFunnaticosChangeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = ReadOnlyPasswordHashField()

    class Meta:
        model = UsuarioFunnaticos

    def clean_password(self):
        return self.initial["password"]
```

Now i'm trying to build a place where the users can go and change their user information, if they wanna change their registered address, phone, etc. My view is below:

```
def alterar_dados(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':        
        form_edicao = UsuarioFunnaticosChangeForm(request.POST)
        if form_edicao.is_valid():
            usuario = UsuarioFunnaticos.objects.get(email=user.request.email)
            usuario.nome_completo = form_edicao.cleaned_data['nome_completo']
            usuario.rua_entrega_cliente = form_edicao.cleaned_data['rua_entrega_cliente']
            usuario.bairro_entrega_cliente = form_edicao.cleaned_data['bairro_entrega_cliente']
            usuario.numero_entrega_cliente = form_edicao.cleaned_data['numero_entrega_cliente']
            usuario.complemento_entrega_cliente = form_edicao.cleaned_data['complemento_entrega_cliente']
            usuario.estado_entrega_cliente = form_edicao.cleaned_data['estado_entrega_cliente']
            usuario.cidade_entrega_cliente = form_edicao.cleaned_data['cidade_entrega_cliente']
            usuario.telefone = form_edicao.cleaned_data['telefone']
            usuario.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/conta')        
    else:        
        form_edicao = UsuarioFunnaticosChangeForm()        
    return render_to_response('conta_cliente/alterar_dados.html', { 'form_edicao': form_edicao }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I also tried it with form_edicao.save(), but both return me the following error:

```
KeyError at /conta/alterardados/

'password'
```

I don't want my users to input their passwords again to change their user information, because they can only get to this part of the website if they are already logged in. Can someone provide some help, please?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you should be passing the existing user object as the `instance` argument when you instantiate the form.

But I don't understand the point of all this mucking about with passwords. If you don't want the password field to be on the form, just add it to the `exclude` list in the form's Meta class.